# Transition matrix not included in my solution of my scheduling problem in CPLEX CP

Tags: optimization, cplex, overlap, job-scheduling, constraint-programming

My distance matrix in my no overlap constraint does not seem to work in my model outcome. I have formulated the distance matrix by means of a tuple set. I have tried this in 2 different ways as can be seen in the code. Both tuple sets seem to be correct and the distance matrix is added in the noOverlap constraint for the dvar sequence.

Nevertheless I do not see the added transition distance between products in the optimal results. Jobs seem to continue at the same time when a job is finished. Instead of waiting for a transition time. I would like this transition matrix to hold both for machine 1 and machine 2.

Could someone tell me what I did wrong in my model formulation? I have looked into the examples, but they seem to be constructed in the same way. So I do not know what I am doing wrong.

mod.

```
using CP;

// Number of Machines (Packing + Manufacturing)
int nbMachines = ...;
range Machines = 1..nbMachines;


// Number of Jobs
int nbJobs = ...;
range Jobs = 1..nbJobs;

int duration[Jobs,Machines] = ...;
int release = ...;
int due     = ...;

tuple Matrix { int job1; int job2; int value; }; 
//{Matrix} transitionTimes ={<1,1,0>,<1,2,6>,<1,3,2>,<2,1,2>,<2,2,0>,<2,3,1>,<3,1,2>,<3,2,3>,<3,3,0>};
{Matrix} transitionTimes ={ <i,j, ftoi(abs(i-j))> | i in Jobs, j in Jobs }; 

dvar interval task[j in Jobs] in release..due;
dvar interval opttask[j in Jobs][m in Machines] optional size duration[j][m];

dvar sequence tool[m in Machines] in all(j in Jobs) opttask[j][m];   

execute {
        cp.param.FailLimit = 5000;
}

 // Minimize the max timespan
dexpr int makespan = max(j in Jobs, m in Machines)endOf(opttask[j][m]);
minimize makespan;
 
subject to {
  // Each job needs one unary resource of the alternative set s (28)
  forall(j in Jobs){
    alternative(task[j], all(m in Machines) opttask[j][m]);
       }     
      forall(m in Machines){
     noOverlap(tool[m],transitionTimes);
       }     
   };

execute {
  writeln(task);
};
```

dat.

```
nbMachines = 2;
nbJobs = 3;

duration = [
        [5,6], 
        [3,4],
        [5,7]
            ];

release = 1;

due = 30;
 
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify interval types for each sequence.
In your case, the type is the job id:

```
int JobId[j in Jobs] = j;
dvar sequence tool[m in Machines] in all(j in Jobs) opttask[j][m] types JobId;
```